# URL after successful logging in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-settings

I have different type of users each with different template.How can I change my URL to

> url(r'^something/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),

from

> url(r'^$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),

when logged in.

my views

```
if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            if user.groups.filter(name='hod').exists():
                return render(request, 'retest/hod.html', {})
            elif user.groups.filter(name='principal').exists():
                return render(request, 'retest/principal.html', {})
            elif user.groups.filter(name='Rep').exists():

                return render(request, 'retest/home.html', {})
            elif user.groups.filter(name='Ajithzen').exists():

                return render(request, 'event/ajithzen.html', {})
            elif user.groups.filter(name='graphics').exists():

                return render(request, 'event/ashok.html', {})    
            elif user.groups.filter(name='Event_incharge').exists():

                return render(request, 'event/incharge.html', {})
            elif user.groups.filter(name='Event_coord').exists():

                return render(request, 'event/chair.html', {})
            elif user.groups.filter(name='IEEE').exists():

                return render(request, 'event/ieee.html', {})
            else:       
                return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})

        else:
            return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
return render(request, 'retest/login.html')
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),
```

Comment: I think you should consider putting each of these responses into their own views and use the login view to route users to their respective views. Each view should have their own URLs

Comment: Could you please explain me.My main problem is after logging in when I refresh or click to go back it goes to this url which is before logged in.What I need is change the url when logged in which is unique to each users.

Comment: added my thoughts in the answers below, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this in your views:

```
# views.py

def login_user(request):
     if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)

            # you have to include a function to retrieve the group that this user belongs to
            ...

            # then, for example if the user belongs to 'hod'
            user_group = 'hod' # for example

# use a dictionary of URL names
            urls = {
            "hod": "user_hod",  # this is just an example, you can use any url name of your preference, more about the url names below
            "principal": "user_principal",
            "Rep" : "user_Rep"
            "Ajithzen" : "user_Ajithzen"
            "graphics" : "user_graphics"
            "Event_incharge" : "user_Event_incharge"
            "Event_coord" : "user_Event_coord"
            "IEEE": "user_IEEE"
            }

# retrieve the url name
            url = urls[user_group] # so if user_group was 'hod', you'd get 'user_hod' here

            return redirect(url)

        else:
            return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Your account has been disabled'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'retest/login.html', {'error_message': 'Invalid login'})
return render(request, 'retest/login.html')


def hod_user(request):
    return render(request, 'retest/hod.html', {})

def principal_user(request):
    return render(request, 'retest/principal.html', {})

def Rep_user(request):
    return render(request, 'retest/home.html', {})
def Ajithzen_user(request):
    return render(request, 'event/ajithzen.html',{})
def graphics_user(request):
    return render(request, 'event/ashok.html',{})
def Event_incharge_user(request):
    return render(request, 'event/incharge.html',{})
def Event_coord_user(request):
    return render(request, 'event/chair.html',{})
def IEEE_user(request):
    return render(request, 'event/ieee.html',{})
```

The idea here is that your `login_user` function will authenticate the user, and check the user's group. Based on this group, the function will redirect the user to his/her respective url, using the `reverse()` method. More about `reverse` and url names [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#django.urls.reverse).

More about redirect [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).

Then in your `urls.py`:

```
# urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login_user'),

    # all your URLs for the different groups
    url(r'^user/hod/$', views.hod_user, name='user_hod'),
url(r'^user/principal$', views.principal_user, name='user_principal'),
url(r'^user/Rep/$', views.Rep_user, name='user_Rep'),
url(r'^user/Ajithzen$', views.Ajithzen_user, name='user_Ajithzen'),
url(r'^user/graphics/$', views.graphics_user, name='user_graphics'),
url(r'^user/Event_incharge$', views.Event_incharge_user, name='user_Event_incharge'),
url(r'^user/Event_coord/$', views.Event_coord_user, name='user_Event_coord'),
url(r'^user/IEEE$', views.IEEE_user, name='user_IEEE'),
    ...
]
```

Here, we have URLs that map each URL to their own view - so each user group should have their own view in your `views.py` which you can create yourself. Generally, here you can think of your `login_user` as a way to route your users to their respective pages.

Comment: Syntyax error with this:  user_group = <'hod', 'principal', 'Rep', 'Ajithzen', 'graphics'Event_incharge', 'Event_coord', 'IEEE'>  @Thomas_Jiang

Comment: You have to assign a string to that variable. The string is the name of the user group for that user that is logging in